# how to create some CSS to align a dropdown menu to a text box

Tags: css, angularjs, textbox, dropdown

I have a text box and when you click on it, a dropdown menu will appear with a list of strings, and when you click on a string, that string will be put in the text box.

I need help with creating some simple css code to align and resize the dropdown menu that appears on click, to match the size of the text box!

this is the code of the text box and the dropdown menu:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 max300" 
                 uib-dropdown is-open="vm.descriptionDropdownOpen">
                <textarea name="description" class="form-control" 
                          ng-model="vm.presence.description" 
                          ng-click="vm.toggleDescriptionDropdown()"
                          autofocus>
                </textarea>
                <ul id="descriptionDropdown" uib-dropdown-menu>
                    <li ng-repeat="descr in vm.loadedDescriptions" 
                        ng-click="vm.presence.description = descr.text;
                                  vm.descriptionDropdownOpen = false;">
                        {{descr.text}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I gave the generated list in the dropdown menu a ID for the css ("descriptiondropdown") and the text box and the dropdown menu look like this:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3mMA.jpg)

the white box you see it s because I edited the entries of the list, but you can see in the background the dropdown menu size and above it the text box size, I'd like them to have the same width and to make the dropdown menu start aligned with the box, not on the left of it.

And for last, if you have some tips on how to affect also the font size and spacing between the entries in the dropdown list for the CSS code would be awesome, thank you

Comment: try with a "width:100%" on the <ul>

Comment: Are you using bootsrap or some other framework?

Comment: bootstrap! thank you for the answer

Comment: I tried with width:100%, but it starts from the container that holds the text box to align, and does not align with the text box! how can I make it start aligned with the text box?

Comment: ok I managed to resolve this with position:relative !